# Populate a nested ObjectRef

Tags: coffeescript, mongoose, populate

So here's my model:

```
CompetitionSchema = new Mongoose.Schema
name :
  type : String
  required : true
required_teams :
  type : Number
teams : [
  _team :
    type : Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId
    ref : 'teams'
  weight :
    type : Number
    min : 0
]
```

I would like to be able to populate a competition object in order to access `competition.teams[0]._team._id` for which I have tried the following:

```
  models('Competition')
  .findById id
  .populate('teams._team')
  .exec (error, competition) ->
    if error || !competition
      error_callback error
    else
      success_callback competition
```

However this has no effect. I've also tried:

```
  models('Competition')
  .findById id
  .exec (error, competition) ->
    if error || !competition
      error_callback error
    else
      options = [
        path : 'teams._team'
        model : 'teams'
      ]
      models('Competition')
      .populate(
        competition
      , options
      , (error, competition) ->
          if error || !competition
            error_callback competition
         else
            success_callback competition
      )
```

Also to no effect. I find the [API documentation for Model.populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate) to be quite confusing, so please excuse me if it's plainly obvious!

Answer (score 0):

OK after soaking myself in the topic a bit more I finally came to the below:

```
  models('Competition')
  .findById id
  .exec (error, competition) ->
    if error || !competition
      error_callback error
    else
      options = [
        path : '_team'
        model : 'teams'
      ]
      models('Team')
      .populate(
        competition.teams
      , '_team'
      , (error, competition_teams) ->
          if error || !competition_teams
            error_callback competition
         else
            success_callback competition
      )
```

It boils down to: Instead of calling

```
Competition.populate(competition, { path : 'teams._team' } , callback);
```

I am now calling:

```
Team.populate(competition.teams, '_team', callback);
```

This has the benefit of modifying the `competition.teams` array rather than returning a copy, so the original `competition` object receives the changes too!